# Pb: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to interpolate data to commune-level using a list comprehension and I keep getting the error in the object on this post.

```py
print("Interpolating engineered features to commune level...")
      covidExtraToCom[['1MMaxpm25','1MMaxpm10','1MMaxo3','1MMaxno2','1MMaxco','pm107davg','pm257davg','o37davg','no27davg','co7davg','pm101Mavg',\
        'pm251Mavg','o31Mavg','no21Mavg','co1Mavg','population','hospi','CovidPosTest' ]] \
          = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum].reindex(columns = ['1MMaxpm25','1MMaxpm10','1MMaxo3','1MMaxno2','1MMaxco','pm107davg','pm257davg','o37davg','no27davg','co7davg','pm101Mavg',\
        'pm251Mavg','o31Mavg','no21Mavg','co1Mavg','idx','hospi','CovidPosTest' ]).values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]

KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'
```

The alternative code below works but doesn't seem ideal for computing time:

```py
 # covidExtraToCom['1MMaxpm25'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["1MMaxpm25"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("1MMaxpm25 interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['1MMaxpm10'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["1MMaxpm10"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("1MMaxpm10 interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['1MMaxo3'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["1MMaxo3"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("1MMaxo3 interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['1MMaxno2'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["1MMaxno2"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("1MMaxno2 interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['1MMaxco'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["1MMaxco"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("1MMaxco interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['pm107davg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["pm107davg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("pm107davg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['pm257davg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["pm257davg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("pm257davg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['o37davg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["o37davg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("o37davg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['no27davg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["no27davg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("no27davg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['co7davg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["co7davg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("co7davg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['pm101Mavg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["pm101Mavg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("pm101Mavg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['pm251Mavg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["pm251Mavg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("pm251Mavg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['o31Mavg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["o31Mavg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("o31Mavg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['no21Mavg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["no21Mavg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("no21Mavg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['co1Mavg'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["co1Mavg"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("co1Mavg interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['population'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["idx"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("population interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['hospi'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["hospi"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("hospi interpolated!")
      # covidExtraToCom['CovidPosTest'] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum]["CovidPosTest"].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
      # print("CovidPosTest interpolated!")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Inside the `.loc`, you are passing a column which is not there in the dataframe.

Comment: I am indeed trying to create new columns in the dataframe on the left

Comment: The error message gives you a url to a page with all the information you need...

Answer (score 1):

Why not the straight forward `for-in` loop?

```py
columns = ['1MMaxpm25','1MMaxpm10','1MMaxo3','1MMaxno2','1MMaxco','pm107davg','pm257davg','o37davg','no27davg','co7davg','pm101Mavg',\
                 'pm251Mavg','o31Mavg','no21Mavg','co1Mavg','population','hospi','CovidPosTest' ]

for col in columns:
    covidExtraToCom[col] = [dfpollution3[dfpollution3['numero'] == depNum][col].values.squeeze() for depNum in covidExtraToCom['dep']]
```